# Rails Javascript onsubmit validate() Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a form of the following characteristics:

```
= nested_form_for reservation, html: { onsubmit: "return validate()"} do ...
```

And the following file reservation.js:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('div.modal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e) {
    ...some code...
  });
  $('div.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    ...some code...
  });

  function validate(){
    var guests = 0;
    $('.guests-input').each(function(i, e){
      guests = guests + $(e).val();
    });
    if (guests < 1){
      alert('Sum of percentage must be 100');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

But, when I click the submit button I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined

I don't know where should I define it. I've searched other questions but I  couldn't solve my problem with them. I'm not entirely sure either where should I look.

I'll edit with more information if needed.

Comment: Put the `validate()` function definition outside jQuery's document.ready handler. Or better yet, attach your event handlers with unobtrusive JS instead of outdated `on*` event attributes

Comment: I thought I tried that, but it seems not because it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Rory McCrossan says on the comment, the solution was to move out the validate() definition outside jQuery's document.ready handler.